# You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate

Tags: android, android-studio, certificate, key, google-play-console

I have an app on Play Store, and I am trying to release an update, I have the jks file and pepk file generated during the first time of release apk, I am using the same jks but google can't verify it

You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
[ SHA1: F8:24 ]
and the certificate used to sign the APK that you uploaded have fingerprint:
[ SHA1: F5:05 ]

Certainly the certificates does not match but it is the same jks file. I don't know what is the problem.
Please any expert here help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely confusing the **app signing key** and the **app upload key**.

When you enroll in Play Signing for an existing app, you are not only uploading this "PEPK file" (the encrypted app signing key), but you are also prompted if you want to generate a separate upload key, and if you do so, you have to create another keystore then also upload the certificate associated with that new key.

I suspect that you generated the upload key and uploaded the certificate and that's the one you should be now signing your APK with. You thus need to change your signing configuration in your build system to point to that new keystore.

If you can't find that keystore that you created then, you'll have to reach out to Google Play Developer support to reset the upload key (where they'll give you the commands to create the keystore for your upload key again).

Comment: thank you for your reply, as I mention, I have both the keystore.jks and pepk file, I really don't know how to properly configure in the build system, any guide would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you create an upload key when you enrolled in Play Signing? You can check that by checking if the certificates are different in the "App Signing" page of the Play Console. If they are different, then you must have created _another_ keystore at that time and you need to find that keystore! Instructions are here on how to change the configuration for Studio/Gradle: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign_release

Comment: I am confused, what is upload key? the jks file which was generated during generate signed apk, or something else?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423 describes all the terms. See "Descriptions of keys, artefacts and tools". It's the JKS file that you created when you enrolled in _App Signing by Play_.